# Does this integral vanish?

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let us define the following function:

$$f(a,b,\tau) := \frac{1}{a^2 + (b-\tau)^2} g(a, b) \tag{1}$$

with $a, b, \tau$ real variables and $g$ some smooth function (piecewise). Now the following integral vanishes:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d\tau\ \partial_\tau f(a, b, \tau) = \left. f(a, b, \tau) \right|^{+\infty}_{-\infty} = 0 \tag{2}$$

for fixed $a$ and $b$. But imagine I would now also be integrating over say the variable $b$. Would the integral still vanish, i.e. would

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} db \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d\tau\ \partial_\tau f(a, b, \tau) \overset{?}{=} 0 \tag{3}$$

also hold? I think it does, except when the integral of $g(a, b)$ diverges, because:

$$\begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} db \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d\tau\ \partial_\tau f(a, b, \tau) &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} db\ g(a, b) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d\tau\ \frac{b-\tau}{(a^2+(b-\tau)^2)^2} \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} db\ g(a, b) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d\tau\ \frac{\tau}{(a^2+\tau^2)^2} \\ &= 0 \cdot\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} db\ g(a, b) \tag{4} \end{align}$$

and the only indeterminate form that we can have out of this is $0 \cdot \infty$, while all other cases are automatically zero. I need to be sure though. Does that all make sense?

Comment: What happens if $a=0$ and $g(a,b)\neq0$? Do you take the Cauchy principal value?

Comment: @Integrand That's a good question, what would happen if I also integrate over $a$? Since the issue would only be at $a=0$, can I remove this point from the integral?